# Flutter: Many bloc providers cluttering widget tree

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, refactoring, bloc, state-management

Im making a type of chat app, and has a need for multiple blocs/repositories/etc. This has lead to my widget tree looking like this:

[image]

And also has lead to a nasty looking build method in my main.dart:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthRepository(),
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (_) => FirestoreRepository(),
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => StorageRepository(),
        ),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => MessagingRepository(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
            create: (context) => AuthBloc(
              authRepository: context.read<AuthRepository>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<BottomnavbarCubit>(
            create: (context) => BottomnavbarCubit(),
            child: MainPage(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<SignupCubit>(
            create: (context) => SignupCubit(
              authRepository: context.read<AuthRepository>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<LocaluserCubit>(
            create: (context) => LocaluserCubit(),
            child: MaterialApp(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<SigninCubit>(
            create: (context) => SigninCubit(
              authRepository: context.read<AuthRepository>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<UpdateCubit>(
            create: (context) => UpdateCubit(
              firestoreRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<ProfileBloc>(
              create: (context) => ProfileBloc(
                    authBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
                    databaseRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>(),
                  )),
          BlocProvider<VoteBloc>(
              create: (context) => VoteBloc(
                  firestoreRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>())),
          BlocProvider<MessageBloc>(
              create: (context) => MessageBloc(
                  firestoreRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>())),
          BlocProvider<LeaderboardBloc>(
              create: (context) => LeaderboardBloc(
                  databaseRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>())),
          BlocProvider<CommentBloc>(
              create: (context) => CommentBloc(
                  firestoreRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>())),
          BlocProvider<EditbioCubit>(
            create: (context) => EditbioCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<CommentCubit>(
            create: (context) => CommentCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<SearchBloc>(
            create: (context) => SearchBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => SwipeBloc(
              firestoreRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>(),
              profileBloc: context.read<ProfileBloc>(),
            ),
          ),
          BlocProvider<StingrayBloc>(
              create: (context) => StingrayBloc(
                    authBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context),
                    databaseRepository: context.read<FirestoreRepository>(),
                  )),
        ],
        child: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider<AuthRepository>(
              create: (_) => AuthRepository(),
            ),
            StreamProvider<List<Stingray?>>.value(
              value: FirestoreRepository().stingrays,
              initialData: [],
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Fishbowl',
            theme: theme(),
            onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.onGenerateRoute,
            initialRoute: Wrapper.routeName,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is this normal? I looked into GetIt, but i read that it is difficult to do dependency injection with blocs. Not sure if this is a fixable issue, or if this is just how working with multiple blocs work. Thank you!

Comment: Rather a fascinating concept. DI and Bloc go hand in hand just not the way you would expect. Please check my answer below to understand the case further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Q: Is this normal? 
> A: Yes, this is perfectly normal. The `MultiBlocProvider` is used in the same way and this is the resulting tree structure.

> Q:  I looked into GetIt, but i read that it is difficult to do dependency injection with blocs 
> A: No, it's not difficult to do DI with Blocs. Rather its very simple. And, it's just like injecting other instance. However, there is a cost and problem associated with it.

You can inject using below code:

```dart
return BlocProvider(
create: (ctx) => getIt<SomeBloc>(),
child: SomeChildWidget(),
);
```

To use `getIt` with `Bloc`, there is only one problem that must be addressed properly.

1. `Bloc`'s cannot and must not be dependency injected in Flutter using `getIt`. The reason being `Bloc` maintains the state changes and creation and destruction of `Bloc`'s and `Cubit`'s. If you just inject it's instance, then `BlocProvider` will always get the same instance with previous states and all. This will cause us to manually reset the state of `Bloc` leading to unnecessary state management which is against the `Bloc`'s principles of state management. `Event`s should update states not us.
2. `Bloc` should not me `DI`ed. However, the dependencies used by `Bloc` can be `DI`ed. FOr instance, `repository` and `data sources` can be injected into the `Bloc`. But never the `Bloc` itself.

We use `Bloc` extensively with `GetIt`, just that we do not use it on the `Bloc` instance itself, rather with the dependencies needed for the `Bloc`'s.

**UPDATE::**

We can use `@injectable` to make new instances of `BLoC`'s as well. However, when we need to pass in parameters in constructor as per usage to `BLoC`, I personally refrain from creating them manually.

Comment: But you write about GetIt's singleton and not factory. I don't see any problems with creating Blocs via GetIt. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @AndreyGritsay You can create Blocs using GetIt. It's perfectly nornal. However, sometimes BLoCs need to be instantiated and destroyed regularly. Consider a Auth Bloc used for Login page only. Creating it using GetIt means its created once and used along the way using same instance. It introduces the need to reset BLoC state manually which is a hassle for some teams. While for others it means more control. Its a personal usecase. I personally dont create BLoCs using GetIt. I like them to be reinsantiated by the engine and hate setting state updates manually. Its a better user experience for us

Comment: I mean just use `@injectable` annotation instead of `@singleton` and you will get the desired behavior

Comment: Yes that works as well...but its a personal preference at this time and I pass in some paramters to BLoCs in the constructor. That is the only reason at this point for me. Other than that, all others are @injectable.

Comment: But you also can provide factory parameters to an injectable. Usually 2 parameters more than enough (for example product id) because you don't have to pass dependencies

Comment: You are absolutely right. It's just preference at this point. Doing either can get the job done Things I did then and I do now are different. So, all is good.